# Is there any chance to get calendar events of other person using app script if their calender is private?

Tags: javascript, email, events, calendar, openmeetings

I am working in a company, I want to access the calendar events of other employees with app script. but I am getting null as there events are private. However I am able to access my own calendar events even if they are private. How can I access my other employees calendar events. I want to send an email with feedback form for all of their events.

this is the code I am using for getting calendar events of specific email. it is giving events if I provide my email but giving null If I provide same domain email of other employee. please help me if you have any thoughts or suggestions.

```
function getAllCalendarEvents() {
  // Get the OAuth client ID and client secret from script properties
  var clientId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('clientId');
  var clientSecret = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('clientSecret');

  // Authorize and set up the Calendar service
  var service = getService(clientId, clientSecret);
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('abc@gmail.com');

  // Retrieve all events from the calendar
  var events = calendar.getEvents(new Date('2000-01-01'), new Date('2100-12-31'));

  // Process the events
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      var event = events[i];
    // Access the event properties
    var title = event.getTitle();
    var startTime = event.getStartTime();


    var endTime = event.getEndTime();
    // Perform further processing as needed
    Logger.log('Event: ' + title + ' (' + startTime + ' - ' + endTime + ')');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid openmeetings label should be removed from this question :)